# Loop through dynamic nested data structures js

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested

I'm loading a JSON from the web and it has dynamic nested arrays, I want to loop through the data and return some items within each parent.

example array:

`{"records": [
  {
      "status": "in Progress",
      "form_values": {
      "1111": "Sam johnes",
      "2222": {
        "choice_values": [
        "John smith"
        ],
        },
      }
  }
  {
      "status": "in Progress",
      "form_values": {
      "1111": "john smith",
      }
  }
  {
      "status": "completed",
      "form_values": {
      "1111": "john smith",
      "2222": {
        "choice_values": [
        "bill smith"
        ],
        },
      }
  }
]
}`

i'm currently using a for loop but it returns a type error because it cannot read property of "choice_values" the loop looks like:

```
   for (i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {

   var status = [data.records[i].status];
   var name = [data.records[i].form_values["2222"].choice_values["0"]];

   var Result = [status, name];

 }
```

Idealy Result would equal:

```
{0} [in progress, john smith]
{1} [in progress, undefined]
{2} [Completed, bill smith]
```

Comment: this isn't the exact code, please ignore some of the spelling mistakes; just an example of the problem I am having with regards to getting an error and filling the empty value with "undefined" or any thing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `var 2222` - vars in javascript can't begin with a digit
2. `var 2222 = [data.records[i].form_values.["2222"].choice_values["0"];` - missing closing `]` ... or, perhaps, the `[` before `data` is incorrect
3. `var status = [data.records[i].status]` - are you sure you want `status` to be an array with a single element?
4. `.form_values.["2222"].choice_values` should be `.form_values["2222"].choice_values` - remove the `.` after `form_values`
5. `var Result = [status, 2222];` - Result will only ever be the value of the LAST iteration of the for loop
6. Your example data is malformed, missing `,` between items of `records` array
7. the second record has no `form_values.2222` property, so your code needs to test for that before blindly assuming it exists

`Result` will be `[ ["completed"], ["bill smith"] ]` - note the nested array - is that your expectation? (I see it isn't)

Fixing all the above:

```js
var data = {
    "records": [{
        "status": "in Progress",
        "form_values": {
            "1111": "Sam johnes",
            "2222": {
                "choice_values": [
                    "John smith"
                ],
            },
        }
    },{
        "status": "in Progress",
        "form_values": {
            "1111": "john smith",
        }
    },{
        "status": "completed",
        "form_values": {
            "1111": "john smith",
            "2222": {
                "choice_values": [
                    "bill smith"
                ],
            },
        }
    }]
};
var Result = data.records.map(function(record) {
    var a2222;
    if (record.form_values["2222"]) {
        a2222 = record.form_values["2222"].choice_values[0];
    }
    return [record.status, a2222];
});
console.log(Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
Look at form_values.["222"].choice_values["0"];
```

It should be

```
Look at form_values["222"].choice_values["0"];
```

Your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {

   var status = [data.records[i].status];
   var Name = [data.records[i].form_values.["2222"].choice_values["0"]];

   var Result = [status, Name];

 }
```